# HTML5 digital signage

Tags: javascript, html, video, video-player

I'm trying to create simple digital signage player based entirely in HTML5/Javascript. Basically, it would have video playing at the center, an rss ticker running at the bottom and html5 animations running on the right.

I'm facing a problem with the video player. I want the video player to randomly play video files from a local folder that is synchronized with dropbox 24h a day.

Here is a picture of my intended layout:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the specific technical problem that you are facing? Also, when you say `local` do you mean local to the user?

Comment: So what exactly do you need help with? What have you tried? Show some code

Comment: Well, I've tried the method on this page. http://www.marceloduende.com/blog/?p=28 The problem is that I want the player to be able to automatically play new videos when they are added to the video folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like PHP to look at directories and generate a JSON list of all videos in that folder.  That part isn't too difficult.  From there you can use something like use AJAX to pull in the JSON  and using Javscript or Jquery randomize the playback of the videos.  Or when creating the JSON you can randomize your list.  I work at a Digital Signage company and have developed something similar.